# How to detect Reference Errors in Javascript where Undefined doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, referenceerror

```
typeof(nonexistingobj)
```

returns 'undefined' BUT

```
typeof(nonexistingobj.nonexistentproperty)
```

does not generate 'undefined' as I was expecting, but something called a [Reference Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) - how do I detect this?

I'm trying to do sub-property detection on the response from an API. (Specifically, the API returns a sub object called `data.paging.next` when there's another page of API results to get, but no 'next' sub object if it just returned the last page).

Comment: You get a ReferenceError when trying to reference a property on an object that does not exist. So in your case, `obj` does not exist (so it's undefined). You can detect this by checking `"undefined" === typeof(obj)`

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function. You use it like `typeof obj.nonexistentproperty`.

Comment: You can detect a ReferenceError by wrapping your call in a [try-catch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to access a property of `undefined`. Test if the variable you are trying to access is defined first.

```
if (typeof obj !== "undefined") {
    typeof obj.nonexistentproperty;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To catch errors you can use try/catch:

```
try {
     console.log(typeof nonexistingobj.nonexistentproperty);
} catch (error) {
     console.log('Message error: ' + error.message);
}
```